# Which view should I use to show a small square containing only a background color, to show a color preview?

Tags: android, android-view, android-viewgroup

I want to display a color for the user to preview. Which `View` should I use?

I want a small square of, say, 100dp.

Comment: The `View` class itself is sufficient. You can set a background color on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally to display custom graphics you would use a `SurfaceView` but in your case you can just use a `View`.

xml:

```
<View android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/my_color"/>
```

Java:

```
View view = new View(this);
view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.my_color);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only color then you can also set it as background color of your **layout** and if you want view then simply use the **View** of andorid SDK.

In both case use **simple line of code in main_layout1.xml of layout or view** as you suits

```
 android:background="@color/my_color"
```